# BeautifulSoup: Can't Access Info Within TD

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm looking at the following website:

https://modules.ussquash.com/ssm/pages/leagues/League_Information.asp?leagueid=1859

I want to extract the name of each university and the href associated with it.  So for the first entry, I'd like to get `Stanford` and `https://modules.ussquash.com/ssm/pages/leagues/Team_Information.asp?id=18564`

I've gotten to the point where I have all of the TDs, using BeautifulSoup.  I'm just having difficulty extracting the school and its href.

Here's my attempt:

```
def main():
    r = requests.get('https://modules.ussquash.com/ssm/pages/leagues/League_Information.asp?leagueid=1859')
    data = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    table = soup.find_all('table')[1]
    rows = table.find_all('tr')[1:]
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        print(cols)
```

When I try to access `cols[0]`, I get:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any idea how to fix this would be awesome!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The first two *tr's* are in the *thead* which have no *td* tags, you want to skip the first two tr's:

```
rows = table.find_all('tr')[2:]
```

To get what you want, we can simplify using  *css selectors*:

```
table = soup.find_all('table', limit=2)[1]

# skip first two tr's
rows = table.select("tr + tr + tr")
for row in rows:
    # anchor we want is inside the first td
    a = row.select_one("td a") # or  a = row.find("td").a
    print(a.text,a["href"])
```

Also the *href* is a relative path so you need to join it to a base url:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.urlparse import  urljoin

def main():
    base = "https://modules.ussquash.com/ssm/pages/leagues/"
    r = requests.get('https://modules.ussquash.com/ssm/pages/leagues/League_Information.asp?leagueid=1859')
    data = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

    table = soup.find_all('table', limit=2)[1]
    # skip first two tr's
    rows = table.select("tr + tr + tr")

    for row in rows:
        a = row.select_one("td a")
        print(a.text, urljoin(base, a["href"]))
```